# How to use Snip() function in VIM

Tags: vim

How I am suppose to use the the snip() function contained in the imaps.vim plugin in the latex package described below:

Snip: puts a scissor string above and below block of text {{{
 Description:

this puts a the string "--------%<---------" above and below the visually
   selected block of lines. the length of the 'tearoff' string depends on the
   maximum string length in the selected range. this is an aesthetically more
   pleasing alternative instead of hard-coding a length.

```
function! <SID>Snip() range
    let i = a:firstline
    let maxlen = -2
    " find out the maximum virtual length of each line.
    while i <= a:lastline
      exe i
      let length = virtcol('$')
      let maxlen = (length > maxlen ? length : maxlen)
      let i = i + 1
    endwhile
    let maxlen = (maxlen > &tw && &tw != 0 ? &tw : maxlen)
    let half = maxlen/2
    exe a:lastline
    " put a string below
    exe "norm! o\<esc>".(half - 1)."a-\<esc>A%<\<esc>".(half - 1)."a-"
    " and above. its necessary to put the string below the block of lines
    " first because that way the first line number doesnt change...
    exe a:firstline
    exe "norm! O\<esc>".(half - 1)."a-\<esc>A%<\<esc>".(half - 1)."a-"
endfuntion
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `:h Snip()`? It should be your very first stop.

Comment: That link is to a file download. You may wish to either mention that it’s a download link or find another alternative page (the home page for the plugin would be good if it has one) to link to — I did not even get taken to a page that described what the plugin was; I clicked this link and the plugin tar immediately began to download (Safari/OS X).

Comment: @Eduan there is no help for this function.

Comment: @ebnezer Sorry for not mention that the link was a download page. So instead I added the function definition in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the line immediately after the `Snip()` definition in `imaps.vim`:

```
com! -nargs=0 -range Snip :<line1>,<line2>call <SID>Snip()
```

This defines the command `Snip`, which can be invoked on any range. In visual mode, vim automatically inserts the range `'<,'>` when you enter a command, so typing `:` and then `Snip`, which results in `:'<,'>Snip`, will call the function on the current selection.

Note that you can also manually specify ranges. For example, `:1,5 Snip` will snip lines 1 through 5, `:'m,'n Snip` will snip from mark `m` to mark `n`, and `:Snip` will apply only to the current line.

In order to avoid having to type `:Snip` every time, you can map this command to a key of your choice. For example, you can map `z` in visual mode to call `Snip` on the current selection as follows:

```
vnoremap z :Snip<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Instead of using Snip in the command I was writing Snip(). Needless to say I just started to learn VIM and I am not very good at it yet.

Comment: @PedroDreyer Just remember that `<SID>` and `s:` in front of function name indicates that this function is not public (consider such functions defined only in script-local scope, though in some cases knowing that they are really global ones named `<SNR>{NR}_*` provides way to write some hacks: see `:h <SID>`). And most of time if something is not documented then it is not a part of public API hence not supposed to be used directly.

Comment: @ZyX I read the help file about `<SID>` and I Understood that it is used to make a mapping exclusive to the script, right? But i cannot imagine an example where it will be necessary, could you provide one please?

Comment: You can search `$VIMRUNTIME` for an example of such mappings (they are additionally `<script>` ones). But this does not make sense to me since `<script>` mappings cannot be restored from the value of `maparg(lhs, mode, abbr, 1)` (note the last argument) and anything else can just be put into a `<SID>` function.